# Pyspark - Parse Nested JSON into Dataframe

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file which looks something like this:

```
{"customer": 10, "date": "2017.04.06 12:09:32", "itemList": [{"item": "20126907_EA", "price": 1.88, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20185742_EA", "price": 0.99, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20138681_EA", "price": 1.79, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20049778001_EA", "price": 2.47, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20419715007_EA", "price": 3.33, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20321434_EA", "price": 2.47, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20068076_KG", "price": 28.24, "quantity": 10.086}, {"item": "20022893002_EA", "price": 1.77, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20299328003_EA", "price": 1.25, "quantity": 1.0}], "store": "825f9cd5f0390bc77c1fed3c94885c87"}
```

I read it using this code :

```
transaction_df = spark \
    .read \
    .option("multiline", "true") \
    .json("../transactions.txt")
```

Output I have :

```
+--------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|customer|date               |itemList                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |store                           |
+--------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|10      |2017.04.06 12:09:32|[{20126907_EA, 1.88, 1.0}, {20185742_EA, 0.99, 1.0}, {20138681_EA, 1.79, 1.0}, {20049778001_EA, 2.47, 1.0}, {20419715007_EA, 3.33, 1.0}, {20321434_EA, 2.47, 1.0}, {20068076_KG, 28.24, 10.086}, {20022893002_EA, 1.77, 1.0}, {20299328003_EA, 1.25, 1.0}]|825f9cd5f0390bc77c1fed3c94885c87|
+--------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Output I am looking for :

```
+--------+--------------+
|customer|      itemList|
+--------+--------------+
|      10|   20126907_EA|
|      10|   20185742_EA|
|      10|   20138681_EA|
|      10|20049778001_EA|
|      10|20419715007_EA|
|      10|   20321434_EA|
|      10|   20068076_KG|
|      10|20022893002_EA|
|      10|20299328003_EA|
+--------+--------------+
```

Basically I am looking for customer and number of items (10 for customer id and its respective purchased item)

Answer (score 2):

You could explode the array and select an item for each row.

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("test.json", multiLine=True)
df = df.withColumn("tmp", F.explode_outer("itemList"))
df = df.select(["customer", "tmp.item"])
df.show(10, False)
df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------------+
|customer|item          |
+--------+--------------+
|10      |20126907_EA   |
|10      |20185742_EA   |
|10      |20138681_EA   |
|10      |20049778001_EA|
|10      |20419715007_EA|
|10      |20321434_EA   |
|10      |20068076_KG   |
|10      |20022893002_EA|
|10      |20299328003_EA|
+--------+--------------+

root
 |-- customer: long (nullable = true)
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to solve this with Spark SQL instead of dataframes.  Both solutions work.  However, this has an important enhancement.

```
#
# 1 - create data file
#

# raw data 
json_str = """
{"customer": 10, "date": "2017.04.06 12:09:32", "itemList": [{"item": "20126907_EA", "price": 1.88, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20185742_EA", "price": 0.99, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20138681_EA", "price": 1.79, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20049778001_EA", "price": 2.47, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20419715007_EA", "price": 3.33, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20321434_EA", "price": 2.47, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20068076_KG", "price": 28.24, "quantity": 10.086}, {"item": "20022893002_EA", "price": 1.77, "quantity": 1.0}, {"item": "20299328003_EA", "price": 1.25, "quantity": 1.0}], "store": "825f9cd5f0390bc77c1fed3c94885c87"} 
"""

# raw file
dbutils.fs.put("/temp/transactions.json", json_str, True)
```

The above code writes a temporary file.

```
#
# 2 - read data file w/schema
#

# use library
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# define schema
schema = StructType([
  StructField("customer", StringType(), True),
  StructField("date", StringType(), True),
  StructField("itemList", 
    ArrayType(
      StructType([
        StructField("item", StringType(), True),
        StructField("price", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("quantity", DoubleType(), True)
      ])    
    ), True),
  StructField("store", StringType(), True)
])

# read in the data
df1 = spark \
  .read \
  .schema(schema) \
  .option("multiline", "true") \
  .json("/temp/transactions.json")

# make temp hive view
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("transaction_data")
```

**This is the most important part of the solution, always use a schema with a text file.**  You do not want the processing code guessing at the format.  This will take considerable time if the file is large.

[image]

We can use the "%sql" magic command to execute a Spark SQL statement. Use the dot notation to reference an element within the array of structures.

If you want to have this data on each row, use the explode command.

[image]

Now that we have the final format, we can write the data to disk (optional).

[image]